# Vite+SvelteKit Build Failing

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm building a website using `SvelteKit`, scaffolded using `pnpm create svelte`. However, when I run `pnpm build`, I get the following error:

```
vite v3.0.9 building for production...
✓ 77 modules transformed.
.svelte-kit/output/client/vite-manifest.json                                           2.96 KiB
[vite-plugin-svelte-kit] Error running plugin hook writeBundle for vite-plugin-svelte-kit, expected a function hook.
error during build:
Error: Error running plugin hook closeBundle for vite-plugin-svelte-kit, expected a function hook.
    at error (file:///home/leo/code/keo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@2.77.3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:1858:30)
    at throwInvalidHookError (file:///home/leo/code/keo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@2.77.3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22551:12)
    at file:///home/leo/code/keo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@2.77.3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22692:24
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Object.close (file:///home/leo/code/keo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@2.77.3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:23662:13)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async build (file:///home/leo/code/keo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.0.9_sass@1.54.7/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0fc8e132.js:43473:13)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///home/leo/code/keo-website/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.0.9_sass@1.54.7/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:747:9)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Here is my `svelte.config.js`:

```js
import adapter from "@sveltejs/adapter-static";
import preprocess from "svelte-preprocess";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
  // for more information about preprocessors
  preprocess: preprocess({
    scss: { includePaths: ["./src/styles"] },
  }),

  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
      pages: "build",
      assets: "build",
    }),
  },
};

export default config;
```

Most things that I've done here are what I've done in the past. The only difference is that I have a `export const prerender = true;` in `src/routes/+layout.svelte` since it appears that they overhauled their route system.

Comment: It looks like a bug on their part. SvelteKit is going through heavy refactor so turbulence is kinda expected. Try revert to earlier version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:**
Vite 3.1.0 is out now, if you just `npm update` the project it should be fine

*Original answer:*

This is because in order to fix `import.meta.glob` issues with vite they needed to require Vite 3.1.0-beta.1 [#6398](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/6398)

The error log mentions `writeBundle` which is a Rollup [hook](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#writebundle) that Vite plugins can  [run](https://github.com/vitejs/rfcs/discussions/12).

You can fix the error by manually updating your `package.json` to contain

```json
{
 ...
 "devDependencies": {
  ...
  "vite": "^3.1.0-beta.1"
 }
}
```

But this Vite version 3.1.0 will soon be released which will then allow to fix the problem with a simple `npm update`